# Angularjs dropdown link with multiple sub items

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

I want to display a dropdown with mutiple sub items please see the picture for example

In the below picture customer is a table right side displayed items are columns i want to display like this in angularjs

example
  customer->name
            city
            Address
  order->name
         quanttity

Comment: What have you tried?
Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edit your question to add it, it will be more understandable.

Comment: i have tried like this but it is not displaying sub items vertically

Comment: please add image as you described..!!